# how to access to ids of selected names in manytomany relationship django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

how to access all ids of `Language`s through `Programmer`

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Programmer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    langs = models.ManyToManyField(Language,through='Level')

class Level(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    programmer = models.ForeignKEy(Programmer)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

i tried this ways but no one worked

in `Programmer` instance : `instance.level_set.language_id` , `instance.level.all.language_id` , `instance.level.all.language.id` and also tried this `instance.level_set.language.id` 
all said Programmer has no attribute ,`language` , `language_id` etc
thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some useful things:

- To get all language id's as an iterable:

```py
instance.langs.values_list('id', flat=True)
# <QuerySet [1, 5]>
```

- Level and language id as a list of 2-tuples:

```py
instance.level_set.values_list('language__id', 'level')
# <QuerySet [(1, 'advanced'), (5, 'beginner')]>
```

Comment: thank you , and what if i want to filter by names from Level something like this . Level.objects.filter(programmer__name='john') this doesnt work , is there something similar that?

Comment: That should work, but maybe your issue is case sensitivity? `Level.objects.filter(programmer__name__iexact='john')`

Comment: If there is no error message, then there simply isn't a programmer named john that has been assigned a language. The programmer may exist, but then you should query him from the Programmer table. In this case, john should show up in this query: `Programmer.objects.filter(langs__isnull=True)`

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following in programmer instance

```
instance.langs.all()
```

for Language Instnace

```
instance.programmer_set.all()
```

[django many to many relationship with extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

--edit--

under your Languages Model define a function

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.id
```

Comment: i want to get id of Languages which selected , its all returns the names not ids

Comment: im wonder why this wont work nstance.level_set.language_id , it should work

Comment: instance.level_set.language_id would work when Level class has Programmer and Language as Foreign keys but it is not a part of many to many relationship. When you define a many to many relationship, accessing property through column name is much more intuitive as well readable and Django implements that. As in your case instance.langs give the reader an idea that it will contain languages of that instance while  instance.level_set is not that intuitive